# How to check Type Ranges with Java development tools (JDT)?

Tags: java, string-parsing, primitive-types, eclipse-jdt

I want to parse a String, which contains a number, using ***JDT*** to find out whether the contained number is inside the valid Range of one of the Primitive Types.

Let's say i got a float value like this as String "*1.7976931348623157e350*" and want to see whether it is still inside the allowed range for primitive type '*double*'. (In this case it would not be inside the valid range, because the maximum exponent of double is 308).
I ***don't*** want to use the standard methods like : `Double.parseDouble("1.7976931348623157e350")`, because I'm afraid it might be too slow if I have a big amount of primitive types, which I want to check .

If you know the Eclipse development environment you will know that inside a normal java file, eclipse is able to tell whether a variable is out of range or not, by underlining it ***red***, in the the case of 'out of range'. So basically i want to use this functionality. But as you can guess - it's easier said then done!

I have started experimenting with the **ASTParser** from this library:   **org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom**

But I must admit I was not very successful here.
First i tried calling some of those vistor methods using methods like:
`resolveBinding()` , but they always only returned me "Null".

I have found some interesting class called `ASTSyntaxErrorPropagator` , but i'm not sure how this is used correctly. It seems to propagate parsing problems or something like that and gets it's information delivered by some thing class called `CodeSnippetParsingUtil` I assume. Anyways, these are only speculations.

Does anyone know how to use this ASTParser correctly?

I would be really thankful for some advice.
Here is some basic code-snipped which I tried to debug:

```
public class DatatypesParser {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS4);

    Map options = JavaCore.getOptions();

    JavaCore.setComplianceOptions(JavaCore.VERSION_1_7, options);

    String statement = new String("int i = " + Long.MAX_VALUE + ";");

    parser.setSource(statement.toCharArray());
    parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_STATEMENTS);
    parser.setResolveBindings(true);
    parser.setBindingsRecovery(true);

    ASTNode ast = parser.createAST(null);

    ast.accept(new ASTVisitor() {
      @Override
      public boolean visit(VariableDeclarationStatement node) {
        CodeSnippetParsingUtil util = new CodeSnippetParsingUtil();

        return true;
      }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want to use the standard methods like :
>   Double.parseDouble("1.7976931348623157e350"), because i'm afraid it
>   might be too slow if i have a big amount of primitive types, which i
>   want to check .

Under the hood JDT is actually using the standard methods of `Double` to parse the value, and quite a bit more - so you should always use the standard methods if performance is a concern.

Here is how the double gets parsed by JDT.

From [`org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.DoubleLiteral`](https://eclipse.googlesource.com/aspectj/org.aspectj.shadows/+/v_552a/org.eclipse.jdt.core/compiler/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/ast/DoubleLiteral.java):

```
public void computeConstant() {
    Double computedValue;
    [...]
    try {
        computedValue = Double.valueOf(String.valueOf(this.source));
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        [...]
        return;
    }
    final double doubleValue = computedValue.doubleValue();
    if (doubleValue > Double.MAX_VALUE) {
        // error: the number is too large to represent
        return;
    }
    [...]
}
```